# Neo4j: add properties to a relation on match and on create

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nodes

My Skript is watching to a folder and will run Cypherqueries if there are any changes.
I try to create a relation between two nodes i created before. When a relation will be created, it should have a "Create Timestamp" and if the node already exist, the relation should update a "Update Timestamp". Here is what i try:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("path/to/my/JSON") yield value 
    WITH value.`Request`.timestamp AS request
    MATCH(a:foo), (c:bar)
    WHERE a.id = c.id
    MERGE(a)-[b:has_relation]->(c)
    ON CREATE SET 
        b += {
            creation_batch_timestamp:trim(request.timestamp)
            }
    ON MATCH SET 
        b += {
            update_batch_timestamp:trim(request.timestamp)
            }
```

What i get back, is a Type mismatch error "expected a map but was a String" (my timestamp is a String)

Is it possible to use a MERGE-Statement for creating or update a relation? How i can solve this?
Thanks for helping :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `request` value is probably already the desired timestamp string.

   Here is one solution. Change this:

   ```
   WITH value.`Request`.timestamp AS request
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   WITH value.Request AS request
   ```
2. It would also be clearer to change this:

   ```
   ON CREATE SET 
     b += {
       creation_batch_timestamp:trim(request.timestamp)
       }
   ON MATCH SET 
     b += {
       update_batch_timestamp:trim(request.timestamp)
       }
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   ON CREATE SET b.creation_batch_timestamp = trim(request.timestamp)
   ON MATCH  SET b.update_batch_timestamp = trim(request.timestamp)
   ```

Comment: Oh yes! I don't know why I didn't see it myself... Now that you told me, it's kind of embarrassing. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Merge is used when you want to create if the relationship doesn't exists, and refresh it otherwise.
So, `ON MERGE SET` would be enough.

So,

```
CALL apoc.load.json("path/to/my/JSON") yield value 
    WITH value.`Request`.timestamp AS request
    MATCH(a:foo), (c:bar)
    WHERE a.id = c.id
    MERGE(a)-[b:has_relation]->(c)
    ON MATCH SET 
        b.timestamp = request.timestamp
```

should works

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But i need two timestamps. With ON MATCH i can just fill and update a single timestamp.
I need the timestamp on time of create of Node and the timestamp on time of update my node.